# Windows 10 (Win 10 UWP VisualStudio project) modular application (like Prism.MEF)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, prism, windows-10, mef

I would like to ask about framework (like Prim.MEF) for building  modular application  which support the Win 10 UWP platform.

Unfortunately, Prism.MEF does not support the Win 10 UWP platform (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but UWP is a different platform than regular .NET (e.g. WPF), the way MEF works in .NET (drop dlls in a folder) is not supported on UWP.

Comment: I would like to build modular application for  the UWP 10 platform and I'm looking for framework which supports UWP 10 platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows apps do not currently support modular development like applications created for the desktop with WPF which support frameworks like MEF where DLLs can just be placed in a way that they can be dynamically loaded by the application.

You could create your application in a way that it has access to all of the "modules" and you restrict them per user if this is an enterprise application or if you're putting it into the store, have them as in-app purchases to unlock (IAP).